# How to show this vector identity involving Laplacian?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Define an operator $L_{+}$ as follows:
$$L_{+} = -\Delta + 1 - pQ^{p-1}$$
Let $Q$ be the solution to the nonlinear PDE:
$$Q-\Delta Q - |Q|^{p-1}Q =0.$$
Let 
$$Q_1 = \left(\frac{2}{p-1} + x\cdot \Delta\right)Q.$$
I want to show that $L_{+}Q_1 = -2Q.$

**Proof Attempt:**
We compute,
$$-\Delta Q_1 = -\left(\frac{2}{p-1}\Delta Q + \Delta[x\cdot \Delta Q]\right)=-\frac{2}{p-1}\Delta Q-x\Delta^2Q-2\nabla Q-\Delta Q d.$$

$$-pQ^{p-1}(Q_1)=-pQ_1^{p-1} = -p\left(\frac{2Q}{p-1}+x\cdot \Delta Q\right)^{p-1}.$$

I am not sure whether I have understood how to apply the operators correctly to the functions given above and therefore I am stuck at this point. Perhaps someone give a few hints since this kind of computation is new to me.

**Background:**
Start with the Nonlinear Schrodinger (NLS) equation:
$$i\partial_t \psi =-\Delta \psi -|\psi|^{p-1}\psi$$
where $\psi(t,x):\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{C}.$ Then we look for solutions called solitary waves that are of the form:
$$\psi(t,x) = Q(x)e^{it}.$$
If you substitute this in the NLS you will get the PDE that I mentioned above.

Comment: 1. Is Q a vector or a scalar? If it is a vector, how does $Q^{p-1}$ work? If it is not a vector, what does $x \color{red} \cdot Q$ mean? 2. Is $\Delta$ the n-dimensional Laplacian? If so, how did you get $-\Delta[x \cdot \Delta Q] = -x \Delta^{2} Q \color{red}{-2 \nabla Q - \Delta Q d}$? 3. I'm not sure how you got $Q^{p-1} Q_{1} = Q^{p-1}_{1}$ either.

Comment: $Q:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{C}.$

Comment: I added some background. Hopefully, this clears some things. I myself do not know how the operators work, I am just guessing at the moment. Apparently the authors of the paper that I am reading think that $L_{+}Q_1=-2Q$ can be proved using trivial computations. So there is no proof given.

Comment: An operator just acts upon an object and transforms the object in some way. Operators must be applied from the correct side (think how matrices often don't commute). Can you just check that $L_{+}$ isn't actually given by $-\Delta + 1 - p \color{red}\lvert Q \color{red}\rvert ^{p-1}$?

Comment: There is no absolute value in the paper. Otherwise, the expression that you wrote is correct.

Comment: @Mattos there was a typo, it should be $-2Q$ and not $-2Q_1.$